# Get list of packages cached in remote repository from Jfrog artifactory

Tags: artifactory

We have our builds pointing to a remote repo in artifactory for installing python packages. We do see the requested packages being cached.

Now we want to get the list of all the packages that are cached along with version information. How do we get this info.?

Tried the REST API for [artifact version search](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactVersionSearch), but it requires a group and an artifact id which we don't have for public packages.

Note: Not looking for all the available versions of packages, rather only the version that is cached for each package.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of querying the remote repository you can query its cache.
The cache can be accessed by adding `-cache` to the repository key. For example, if you have a remote repository named `pip`, you can query a repository named `pip-cache` instead. This will include only the cached artifacts.

See the following article in JFrog's knowledge base: [Remote repository how it works, pull replication with other Artifactory server and the ability to use only the cached artifacts](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/remote-repository-how-it-works-pull-replication-with-other-artifactory-server-and-the-ability-to-use-only-the-cached-artifacts/)

Some other useful and relevant articles:

- [How Remote Repository Metadata works](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-remote-repository-metadata-works/)
- [Remote Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Remote+Repositories) documentation